# Question regarding Kylo Ren line

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

**The Force Awakens Spoilers**

I've just got back from seeing The Force Awakens, and I was curious about a line Kylo Ren says.

When he's looking at Vaders helmet, he says "Grandfather". Given that he is Han's son, why does he say Grandfather? Or, did I mishear his line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because Kylo Ren is the son of Han Solo and Leia Organa, and since Leia is Darth Vader’s daughter, Kylo Ren is Darth Vader’s grandson.

Comment: Doh, I was getting mixed up, for some reason I thought he was saying he's Luke's grandson (don't ask why haha). Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @TomHart Mark Hamill has aged, but not that much! ;-)